# How can I prompt user for multiple inputs, then print summary to a file?

Tags: python, file, input, printing

So far I'm able to print at the end if the user selects 'n' to not order another hard drive, but need to write to a file. I've tried running the code as 'python hdorders.py >> orders.txt', but it won't prompt for the questions; only shows a blank line and if I break out using Ctrl-C, it writes blank entries and while loops in the file. I hope this makes sense.

```
ui = raw_input("Would you like to order more hard drives?(y/n) ")
if ui == 'n':
    print '\n','\n',"**** Order Summary ****",'\n',row,'\n',"Number of HD's:",b,'\n',"Disk Slot Position(s):",c,'\n',"Disk Size(s):",d,"GB",'\n',"Dimensions:",e,'\n','\n',
    endFlag = True
```

I'd also like it so that if they select 'y', it will save to a file and start over for another disk order (saving the previous info to the file first). Then once they are done (for example going through the program twice) and select 'n', it will have the final details appended to the same file as the first order.

Comment: I tried my best to provide all the code but kept getting format errors and it wouldn't let me include it in the post it.

Comment: Your print statement could also be compressed into one formatted string like `print("\n\n**** Order Summary ****\n{0}\nNumber of HD's: {1}\nDisk Slot Position(s): {2}\nDisk Size(s):{3}GB\nDimensions: {4}\n\n".format(row, b, c, d, e))` I think having all the input at the end also makes it easier to update/change what variables get displayed in strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that when extensive user input is desired, a GUI may be the best option. I only try to do command line input if my script uses a small amount of user inputs that I can argparse out. Personally, I would make a tkinter combobox for each of these inputs and have a button at the bottom of the GUI that processes all the inputs and writes them to a file. Here is a skeleton of how I make a GUI

```
import tkinter as tk


class OOP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("My Title")
        self.user_input = tk.StringVar()
        self.create_widgets()

    def lookup_csv_file(self):
        file = self.user_input.get()
        print(file)

    def create_widgets(self):
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Lookup CSV file", width=42, command=self.lookup_csv_file).pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        tk.Entry(self.win, textvariable=self.user_input).pack(expand=1, fill='both')


app = OOP()
app.win.mainloop()
```

This code shows several important things to note:

1) GUI's should be made with Object Oriented Programming (OOP) for most cases

2) The variables you want to keep should be initialized in the `__init__` section as tk.StringVar(), tk.IntVar(), etc.. and then attached to GUI sections (as seen in `create_widgets(self):` section the entry's text variable is attached to our varible

3) To access the variable you use its .get() method as seen in `lookup_csv_file` section. As well the variable has a .set() method if you would like to put a value there. For instance you can do `self.user_input = tk.StringVar()` followed with `self.user_input.set('Default CSV file')` and the GUI will initialize with that shown.

4) When assigning commands to buttons, do not include the `()`. If instead of `command=self.lookup_csv_file` you put `command=self.lookup_csv_file()` the command will run during initialization.

These are some of the finer points that were hard for me to learn, but with this you should be able to quickly learn by looking at the documentation available!

Comment: here's unofficial tkinter documentation: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ note that this does not cover themed tkinter (ttk) which is where you'd find the comboboxes I mentioned. But there are tk modules that have similar usages!

Comment: I will look into it thanks. It's also good for raw input? There are a few questions in the program that can't use comboboxes. For example the first question "Name of server" references a csv file.

Comment: Yes, you can use a `tkinter.Entry()` and this makes a generic text field for the user to fill out with whatever they please!

Comment: OK thanks, but using tkinter I have to learn how to do all of my code all over again. lol. I'm now having a hard time finding a thread for how to have the user input a server name and it then looks it up in csv file and displays the row (data) for that server. That's the only outstanding piece for me using tkinter. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristopherMetcalf I've added an example of how you could set it up! Hope this answers your question and you can accept the answer, so the thread will close

Comment: Oh this is a Python 3.5 example, but I think it works the same or similarly in 2.X

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried running the code as 'python hdorders.py >> orders.txt', but it won't prompt for the questions

You don't see the prompts since you redirect the standard output, whereto also the prompts go, to the file `orders.txt`. Better [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) the file within your program, without redirection at the shell:

```
if ui == 'n':
    orders = open('orders.txt', 'a')    # 'a' for appending
    print >>orders, '\n','\n',"**** Order Summary ****",'\n',row,'\n',"Number of HDs:",b,…
    orders.close()
```

- run as `python hdorders.py`.